# How can I chain two rails Queries together elegantly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count, find

I have the following model object:

```
#<Insight id: 155, endorse_id: 15, supporter_id: 15, created_at: "2011-09-22 02:27:50", updated_at: "2011-09-22 02:27:50">
```

Where Endorse has_many insights and Supporter has many insights.

I can query the db in the following way:

> > Endorse.find(15).insights.count
> >
> > Insight.find_all_by_supporter_id(15).count

**How can I elegantly chain both of these queries together where I can search for all Insights created by Endorse 15, and Supporter 15?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Rails2:

insight_count = Insight.count(:conditions => {:supporter_id => 15, endorse_id => 15})
insights      = Insight.all(:conditions => {:supporter_id => 15, endorse_id => 15})

Rails3:

insight_count = Insight.where(:supporter_id => 15, endorse_id => 15).count
insights      = Insight.where(:supporter_id => 15, endorse_id => 15).all
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

For Rails 3.0.x and probably 3.1

```
Endorse.find(15).insights.find_all_by_supporter_id(15).count
```

For Rails 2.3.x

```
Endorse.find(15).insights.find_all_by_supporter_id(15).length
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you would want to chain them together since each one is a different query.  If there were relationships between them, then it would make sense to me.  For example, if Endorse contained Insights which contained Supporters.

Comment: rwilliams answer makes sense if you are wanting to find all insights with supporter_id = 15 from the results of the first query... which looks like what you are wanting to do from re-reading the last line of your post :)